# What is the proper way to center and crop an image using bootstrap (with jquery if needed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, thumbnails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use **bootstrap** and I would like to display thumbnails of images from various sizes.

I would like the thumbnails to have all the same size (let's say `width="col-md-2"` wide and `height="100px"`) and be centered and cropped.

The thumbnails have to be clickable in some way (to open the full size image or a gallery view).

The solution can use a mix of `bootstrap styling` or `jquery` or `jquery components`.

Ideally, I would like the code to look like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="..." style="...">
       <img src="path/to/img1.png" class="..." style="..."/>
       <img src="path/to/img2.png" class="..." style="..."/>
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Or something like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="..." style="...">
       <div class="..." style="...">
          <img src="path/to/img1.png" class="..." style="..."/>
       </div>

       <div class="..." style="...">
          <img src="path/to/img2.png" class="..." style="..."/>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(With the jquery initialization if necessary)

Comment: What do you mean by `be centered and cropped`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
.row {
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

img {
   width:100%;
   min-height:100px;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/92024

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you mean these examples below by "cropping."

[**Original photo**](http://www.theepochtimes.com/n2/images/stories/large/2010/12/15/iron_man_3_91475733.jpg)

[**Cropped in fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GbtCZ/2/)

```
border-color: white;
border-radius: 63px;
border-style: solid;
```